# WPF. Биндинг между двумя окнами

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

В приложении на wpf имеется два окна MainWindow1 и MainWindow2
мне нужно забиндить свойство Width окна MainWindow2 к MainWindow1 и его свойству ActualWidth
что то вроде этого, но это не работает:

```
Width="{Binding  Source={x:Static views:MainWindow1.ActualWidthProperty}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сослаться на свойство *экземпляра* через `x:Static` не получится.

Самый простой вариант — сообщить одному окну о другом через code-behind. Например, можно сделать так. Вы убираете из `App.xaml` указание `StartupUri`, и пишете в `App.xaml.cs`

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    var mainWindow = new MainWindow1();
    var otherWindow = new MainWindow2();

    mainWindow.SetBinding(
        Window.WidthProperty,
        new Binding("Width") { Source = otherWindow, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });

    mainWindow.Show();
    otherWindow.Show();
}
```

Voilà, у вас связаны ширины двух окон.